# How to get labeltext on the same line?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am using bootstrap 3 for my styles. Trying to get the labeltext ie 'mycomp accountnumber' on 1 line :

```css
.lab {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<section className="serviceDetails">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-lg-3">
      <div className="col-lg-2">
        <img src="/pic.png" width="30px" height="60px" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-9 lab">
        <label className="lab" htmlFor="accountNr">mycomp account number</label>
        <span> 1378173871237817</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried inline block, but am still getting mycomp account and then number on the next line. How can I get mycomp account number on 1 line?

Comment: `<label>` element by default is already set to `display: inline-block;`, I'm not sure what you mean that they are blocked instead. Btw, it's `class` and not `className`. Here's a codepen for you to review http://codepen.io/yongchuc/pen/VKoOLq

Comment: I have run your code snippet, it works well. May be other css styles have conflict with the `<label>` style. You can debug it in your devtools.

Comment: also the image does is not centered how can I do this? I tried center-block.

Answer (score 0):

separate as two column

```
  <div className="col-lg-9 lab">
              <div className="col-sm-6">  <label className="lab" htmlFor="accountNr">mycomp account number</label></div>
         <div className="col-sm-6">
                <span> 1378173871237817</span>
        </div>
              </div>
```